# Can I check if user download whole csv correctly?

Tags: downloadable

I create `csv` file for user like that:

```
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($name.'.csv', $csv, 'type/csv');
```

Can I check if user download whole csv correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do this using php. Have a look at [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563187/check-if-download-is-completed) for some more info.

If you don't need this for an automated process, but rather to give the client certainty that they downloaded the file ok, maybe it's better to [provide a checksum and ask users to validate the integrity of the downloaded files](http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?305).